# ServeRAID 8i setup

Tags: raid, scsi, ibm

I purchased a second hand IBM eServer x345 with ServeRAID 8i and 3x 36GB SCSI hard drives.

I'm having difficulty setting up an operating system as the drives don't appear in either Arch or Ubuntu Server (even after select the ips drivers)

The individual disks show up in the server's onboard diagnostics software, but no logical volumes show up either there or in the BIOS.

Is there anything special I'll need to do to set these drives up with ServeRAID? Preferably I'd like just a JBOD configuration, but I'm happy with anything if I can just get this thing running.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the RAID driver when booting from the OS installation CD.

Comment: I loaded Ubuntu's ips driver during installation but it can't see any volumes. There's information about my disks and ServeRAID BIOS in /proc though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same thing, but my Googling led me to believe that I had to configure the controller before installing the operating system using [this bootable CD](http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=migr-64669%20). <s>Unfortunately, the CD did not detect my ServeRAID 8I controller on my MXE 460, but it might work for you.</s> It turns out I didn't have a card in my server in the first place. DERP. This solution should work for everyone.